# Removal from an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am beginner to java but after a hard struggle I could not understand the following reason

I have two ArrayLists Like..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

      public class ArrayListManipulation
     {

    ArrayList<String> listOne = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();

    void add()
    {

        listOne .add("First");

        listOne .add("Second");

        listTwo.add(listOne);

    }

    void remove()
    {
        listTwo.remove(0);


     }
  }
```

My problem is that when I remove the object from index zero in ListOne then ListTWo also changed, but

when I remove element from index zero in ListTwo then ListOne remains unchanged.

Please explain the reason in simple words...

Comment: What do you mean? Doing something to `listTwo` does absolutely nothing to `listOne`.

Comment: You're storing references, not values.

Comment: This is because listTwo depends on listOne and listOne does not depend on listTwo

Comment: Yes listOne remains unchanged

Comment: When ArrayList stores the references then there should be a change in listOne also because both points same location

Comment: `both points same location` You mean `listOne` and `listTwo`? Why do you think that?

Comment: But you're not changing `listOne` in any way, only `listTwo`. `remove()` doesn't mean remove from memory, if you're coming from a C-background. It just means remove the reference to `listOne` from the list of items referenced by `listTwo`.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `listTwo.remove(0);` will in fact remove `listOne` as an element of `listTwo`, but will not alter `listTwo` (i.e. remove its elements) in any way, since you are **referencing** `listTwo`.

You can add `listOne.clear()` if you wish to remove all its elements.

For instance, to clear everything in your "nested" `List`s, instead of referencing an index:

```
listTwo.clear();
listOne.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

listTwo is an ArrayList which contains a list of ArrayList *references*. When you delete the element 0 from listTwo, you simply remove its *reference* to listOne, leaving listOne unaffected.

If you want to access and modify listOne from listTwo, you'd have to do something like:

```
listTwo.get(0).remove(1); // Retrieves listOne (at index 0), and removes its 2nd element (at index 1)
```